# Query junction table without getting both associations in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Consider the following models:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  _id:{
    type: Datatypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: Datatypes.STRING,
  email:{
    type: Datatypes.STRING,
    unique: {
      msg: 'Email Taken'
    },
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
});

var Location= sequelize.define('Location', {
  _id:{
    type: Datatypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: Datatypes.STRING,
  address: type: Datatypes.STRING
});

Location.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserLocation'});
User.belongsToMany(Location, {through: 'UserLocation'});
```

Is there a way to query the `UserLocation` table for a specific `UserId` and get the corresponding `Locations`.  Something like:

`SELECT * FROM Locations AS l INNER JOIN UserLocation AS ul ON ul.LocationId = l._id WHERE ul.UserId = 8`

From what I can find you can do something similar to:

```
Location.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: User,
    where: {
      _id: req.user._id
    }
  }]
}).then( loc => {
  console.log(loc);
});
```

However, this returns the `Locations`, `UserLocation` junctions, and `User` which it is joining the `User` table when I do not need any user information and I just need the `Locations` for that user.  What I have done is working, however,  the query against the junction table is prefered instead of the lookup on the `User` table.

I hope this is clear.  Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I actually ended up implementing this in a different way.  However,  I am still going to leave this as a question because this should be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

declaring junction table as separate class, something like this

```
var UserLocation = sequelize.define('UserLocation', {
  //you can define additional junction props here
});

User.belongsToMany(Location, {through: 'UserLocation', foreignKey: 'user_id'});
Location.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserLocation', foreignKey: 'location_id'});
```

then you can query junction table same as any other model.

Comment: Could you provide the way you would use the `UserLocation` table to produce exactly the query the OP is asking about? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't try it now because i haven't live sequelize project here. But I am pretty sure that you can use junction table as any other table without harm to relations definition. In worst case you can daclare foreign key columns on UserLocation explicitly, but I guess they are defined on class by sequelized. (Similar to id column, declared automatically, but if you redeclare it explicitly nothihng happens) And after that you should be able use UserLocation as basic foreign key and construct query in same way.

Comment: This still doesn't let you join one of the association entities with the junction table without the other association entity.